# Magento1.9 - shared cart - force checkout in product store

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.2.4

When using multi-store with shared cart across all stores eg:

Store1 - ProductA
Store2 - ProductB

When in Store1, add ProductA to cart.
Navigate to Store2 > cart > checkout

How can I force the customer to checkout in Store1? 
(eg not checkout in current store: store2)

So use the Store ID of the product currently in the cart for the checkout process.

The reason: I have different currency for each store, using this:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Directory/etc/system.xml:
<label>Base Currency</label>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

I need to force checkout in the currency for the product (product store base currency)

I don't want to use multiple websites.
Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: Can anyone assist?

Comment: I found this on Stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882442/redirect-magento-user-to-different-store-view-checkout-product-page-based-on-p

Can anyone help advise on how this is achieved? 
as I can't work out how to implement